# SimpleCV installed on windows but not working

Tags: python

I just have installed `SimpleCV` on windows 8 , but when i check it with  `import SimpleCV` , I get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "(stdin)", line 1 , in (module)
>   ImportError: No module named SimpleCV

I uninstalled it and installed it again many times .. 
  When I check the other modules that come with SimpleCV like `pygame` or `scipy` , It works ..

Can I know what is the probleme with the module : "SimpleCV" ?

Thank you

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. Are you sure the module is meant to be imported with the camel-cased name?

Comment: @PauloScardine: The author is correct; I've checked that.

Comment: What do you mean Paulo ?

Comment: @PauloScardine meant, are you sure you didn't write `import simplecv`, or something other than `import SimpleCV`, the correct name of the module?

Comment: Are you using something like `virtualenv`, `pyenv` or `conda`?

Comment: SimpleCV seems to need Python 2.7. Is it possible that you're trying to import it in Python 3?

Comment: i don't think so , because I had removed Python , and installed SimpleCV which contains Python 2.7 ..

Comment: Looks like a `PATH` issue; try to add the SimpleCV library path to your `PATH` environment setting. Also, make sure you don't have an `OpenCV.py` or `OpenCV` folder around, because this may shadow the original library.

Comment: I found OpenCV.py in PYTHONPATH , but should I delete it ? what is the path that should put in PYTHONPATH ?